# Model path injection and gcsfuse

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcsfuse

I observed that VertexAI uses gs:// rather than /gcs as the path to store trained models (started a few days ago).

In my understanding, when gcsfuse is mounted correctly (which is the case for me - according to the logs), then I would expect nothing else than /gcs/path_to_where_to_store_a_model as per the documentation. Am I doing something wrong, or did something change?

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: According to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/code-requirements#fuse), Cloud Storage FUSE is used to mount the Cloud Storage buckets.When you start a custom training job it sees a directory /gcs containing all the Cloud Storage buckets as subdirectories and the job visits the subdirectories (ie. buckets) when certain permissions are granted. The training jobs can be read from file `/gcs/example-bucket/data.csv` to get the training data stored in object `gs://example-bucket/data.csv`. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi @ShipraSarkar thanks for your feedback. You are correct to point to the documentation. So I have some component that outputs an artifact. In a normal situation, it's either kubeflow or VertexAI that determines what that path for that artifact is. However, what I observed is that, before my post that path was gcs/something_somthing (as expected, hence gcsfuse). Now I notice, that this changed to gs://something_somthing. So I wonder, why that is? If gcsfuse was not mounted, then I would expect this. But it's mounted correctly (automatically by vertexAI btw) so this makes me wonder.

Comment: Hi @EiJay, can you confirm whether the path is still `gs://` or it changed to `/gcs`?

Comment: @ShipraSarkar It's still gs://

Comment: Can you check your code that maps GCS FUSE paths to 'classic' gcs paths for reading/writing and the back-conversion for output purposes?